# Monitoring of Logging

Tags: windows, logging, ftp, log-analysis

I wish to implement logging and auditing features on a Windows 10 client used for carrying out secure transactions through our FTP server, with a client organisation.

What all features could I select in the Windows' auditing options, so that I could make it very useful to detect malware, unauthorised admin privilege usage, unauthorised network usage, and etc?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I've worked in secure file transfer software and I am currently in log collection.

Are you carrying out managed file transfers? For example, you have a secure file transfer configuration rules set to automate certain tasks. Or do you mean that you have a Win 10 machine set up with a GUI file transfer software that is being used by a user?

Also this is on the FTP protocol, right? Not like FTPES/FTPIS? Is the network accessible as something like a VPN for local network? AFAIK, some users still use FTP but under certain circumstances, and any other circumstance we'd recommend they use FTPS.

--

> I could make it very useful to detect malware, unauthorised admin privilege usage, unauthorised network usage, and etc?

To start, here's a few to look into:

**Windows EventLog collection**. To start, check out *Malware Archaelogy's talk Security Compliance - Finding Advanced Attacks* PDF via search which lists out EventIDs to log and monitor.

**Windows Registry Monitoring**. To monitor changes in the registry made by Windows or a certain program.

**Windows DNS Monitoring** ie monitor any calls to CnC servers.

If you have any important files (like the file transfer configuration file) you may want to implement **file integrity monitoring** to monitor for any changes to this file.

Then you would want to collect these logs with something like [NXLog](https://nxlog.co/) (disclaimer, I am involved in that project) and send these out to a centralized log server on the event that the FTP client is unavailable or goes down.

Comment: Excellent answer!